# Django's introspecting administrator: How does it work?

Tags: python, django

I don't really want to know Django I am actually more interested in the administrator. The thing that interests me is how they introspect the models to create the administrator back-end.

I browsed through the Django source code and found a little info but since it's such a big project I was wondering if there are smaller examples of how they do it?

This is just a personal project to get to understand Python better. I thought that learning about introspecting objects would be a good way to do this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With Django it's a bit more than introspection actually. The models use a metaclass to register themselves, I will spare you the complexities of everything involved but the admin does *not* introspect the models as you browse through it.

Instead, the registering process creates a `_meta` object on the model with all the data needed for the admin and ORM. You can see the `ModelBase` metaclass in `django/db/models/base.py`, as you can see in the `__new__` function it walks through all the fields to add them to the `_meta` object. The `_meta` object itself is generated dynamically using the `Meta` class definition on the model.

You can see the result with `print SomeModel._meta` or `print SomeModel._meta.fields`

Answer (score 1):

This might get you started:

```
>>> class Foo:
...   x = 7
...
>>> f = Foo()
>>> dir(f)
['__doc__', '__module__', 'x']
>>> getattr(f, 'x')
7
```

Comment: I have a small side question. Why ain't there no parentheses when declaring Foo? I see this in the class Meta too in the Django models.

Comment: Parents of the class would go in parenthesis after the `class Foo`.  You can leave the parens off if there are no parents.  [New-style base classes](http://docs.python.org/glossary.html#term-new-style-class) would always have a parent of `object`

Answer (score 0):

If you really want to know how it works in order to learn Python, I would suggest looking at the source code. It is actually pretty well documented.

http://code.djangoproject.com/browser/django/trunk/django/contrib/admin

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I am already doing this but the Django project is a big and vast place to wonder around with my knowledge of Python.

Comment: It is big, but it is also well structured. IMHO, being able to read and comprehend code is the most important skill in industry. Which, like every skill, takes time and practice to learn.